# Using F-type Coaxial jack for Internet?

Tags: internet, home-networking, internet-connection, coaxial

I just moved into a new townhouse and there are f-type coaxial wall jacks in every room, but no Ethernet jacks. I don't have a TV/cable, I just have a bunch of computers. Is it possible to convert or use these jacks for Internet connectivity?

Also, if I did have a bunch of Ethernet jacks, would they all automatically connect to my network or do they all have to be connected to my router somehow?

Comment: "do they all have to be connected to my router" Of course. Or to a switch that is connected to your router.

Comment: You can buy ethernet to coax converters ...

Comment: So if I attach my router to one of the coaxial jacks, then anything connected to a coaxial jack in another room is connected to the router or no?

Comment: Correct. But you will need converters at each end of the coax. And you will need to find where the other ends of the coax cables are ... you don't want to be daisy chaining them ...

Comment: If they're all just ports in the walls, how do I know where the ends are?

Comment: Ask the builder?

Comment: @user7784 well your going to have to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are devices known as ethernet to coax adapters, many of which are pricey, especially if you are considering to use "a bunch of computers" but may be the least expensive method to use existing wiring.

If your house is wired in what is known as "home-run" format, each outlet in the rooms will run to a central location, allowing you to use a multi-port ethernet-to-coax device. It is unusual to have a residence wired otherwise.

Your second question regarding connectivity overlooks an important aspect of any wiring. There is an outlet in a room. It goes somewhere else. That location has to be connected "somehow" to a resource, typically a router.

In the case of the coax adapters, the central location would become the resource for your router as well.

Examine closely the requirements for these devices, as well as the features offered among the wide variety of products on the market. Newer wiring will be of the form of RG-6, a larger diameter and higher capacity than older RG-59 and is preferred over the older, less capable RG-59 wiring.

Connector installation should be done with proper tools to maintain coaxial cable transmission characteristics. Crushing a connector with pliers is contra-indicated.

Your last question about location of the central location can be answered often by the cable company, especially if service has been provided to your residence in the past. It is usually in an attic over a garage or a sheltered location on the outside, called a demark.